# Using android:action to launch activity from settings

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I have defined my settings.xml file to include an item that uses  android:action item in the setting dialog. See the sample code for that activity below. It all works fine. However this thing is "overlaying" my entire activity and when user presses back button my entire application finishes. Is there a way to launch a "Fragment" using android:action in settings.xml or how I can restructure my activity so when that activity finishes my main activity is resumed?

```
<PreferenceScreen>
    <Preference android:title="Current User" >
        <intent android:action="com.example.coreui.ShowCurrentUserActivity"
        />
    </Preference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

here is the activity code

```
public class ShowCurrentUserActivity extends Activity {
    public  AlertDialog dialog = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String msgStr;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Logout",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    ShowCurrentUserActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Dismiss",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    ShowCurrentUserActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is how I specifiy activity in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.coreui.ShowCurrentUserActivity"
        android:label="CurrentUser"
        android:exported="false">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.coreui.ShowCurrentUserActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Could you solve your problem using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html ?

Comment: But question really is how to I invoke that Fragment using <action android:name=...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine if the dialog is an activity itself. Also it is possible to create an activity which is showing only a Fragment. (I'll edit my answer soon.)

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.gyebro.settingsintent" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ShowCurrentUserActivity"
        android:label="Show Current User"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.gyebro.settingsintent.SHOW_CURRENT_USER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
}
}
```

**pref_headers.xml**

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<header android:title="Intent"
    android:summary="Launches my Activity">
    <intent android:action="com.gyebro.settingsintent.SHOW_CURRENT_USER" />
</header>
</preference-headers>
```

**ShowCurrentUserActivity.java**

```
public class ShowCurrentUserActivity extends Activity {
public AlertDialog dialog = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
}
}
```

and finally **dialog.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Do you want to sign out?"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/textview" />
<LinearLayout
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2">
    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign out"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />
    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]  [image]

**E D I T**
Here's an example, when you have a Dialog Fragment wrapped in an Activity. You need to finish the activity after the user interacts with the Dialog. Unless you use the Dialog Fragment at other places too, I recommend using the above solution.

**ShowCurrentUserActivity.java**

```
public class ShowCurrentUserActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "ShowCurrentUserActivity";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Show the dialog
    ShowCurrentUserDialog fragment = new ShowCurrentUserDialog();
    fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "ShowCurrentUserDialog");
}
public void doPositiveClick() {
    // Do stuff here.
    Log.d(TAG, "Dialog positive click");
}
public void doNegativeClick() {
    // Do stuff here.
    Log.d(TAG, "Dialog negative click");
}
public void dialogDetached() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Dialog detached, finishing now...");
    finish();
}
}
```

**ShowCurrentUserDialog.java**

```
public class ShowCurrentUserDialog extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle("Sign out")
            .setMessage("Do you want to sign out?")
            .setPositiveButton("Sign out",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            ((ShowCurrentUserActivity)getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
                        }
                    }
            )
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            ((ShowCurrentUserActivity)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
                        }
                    }
            )
            .create();
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    ((ShowCurrentUserActivity)getActivity()).dialogDetached();
}
}
```